# ng-table group data based on the key value in object

Tags: angularjs, data-structures, ngtable

I am using ng-table to display some data. The data is of the following format,

```
var data = [{alpha: "howareyou",
            beta:[{field1: num, field2: num2}, {field1: num2, field2: num3}]
            },
            {
            }, {}....]
```

The grouping should be done according to "alpha" and the data to be displayed is stored in beta, i.e., "field1" and "field2".
Specifically how do I write the function in ngTableParams to handle this?